# Get array object from return value

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function to get the window size.

```
function viewport() {
   var e = window, a = 'inner';

   if ( !( 'innerWidth' in window ) ){
     a = 'client';
     e = document.documentElement || document.body;
   }

  return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] }
}
```

I get the code here: [https://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewportwindo....](https://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewportwindow-size-width-and-height-javascript)

Now, my question is how can I retrieve the value of `width` only?

I've already tried this one,

```
var width = viewport();
console.log(width);
```

Sample output is: `Object {width: 1182, height: 297}`

Note: I don't want to change the return value to `return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] }` only because I might use the `height` value on some other time.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var width = viewport(); width.width` ? Am I missing something here! For more details [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport returns an object and so you need to access the object properties by using either

```
viewport().width
```

or

```
width.width
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
console.log(viewport().width);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11312761)

Comment: @maxhb well the OP wanted to access the `width`. My answer clearly shows how to do it. The marked answer by OP is the same, i see no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the width part:

```
return e[a + 'Width'];
```

or of the result the value of the width property

```
var width = viewport().width;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to reference it:**

```
var width = viewport().width;
```